# I am getting log in stripe but it show no payments in payment option

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am working on stripe connection and i am getting the log of data and it 200 means api is hitting but i am not getting payments and its not showing in payment optino of stripe 
my code that i am using is

```
<button id="customButton" class="submit_btn">Make Appointment</button>
                    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
                    <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken" name="stripeToken" />
                    <script>
                       var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                            key: 'TOKEN',
                            image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
                            locale: 'auto',
                            token: function(token) {
                                jQuery(function ($) {
                                    console.log("testing12");
                                    $('#stripeToken').val(token.id);

                                });
                            }
                        });
                        jQuery(function ($) {
                            document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                                var amount =  0;
                                $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                                    amount  += isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
                                    $('#total').text(amount); 
                                });
                                handler.open({
                                    name: 'Sports Solution',
                                    description: '',
                                    amount: amount
                                });
                                e.preventDefault();
                            });
                        });
                        // Close Checkout on page navigation:
                        window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
                            handler.close();
                        });
```

I dont know where i am doing it wrong.

Comment: your code is `tokenization` portion; you will need to actually create a charge use the token in order to see them on your dashboard. You could follow Stripe document at https://stripe.com/docs/charges on how to create charges

Comment: where i have to add this as when i add this code it give error for jquery

Comment: you will need a backend server e.g. setting a simple node server to host the charge endpoint. You could following 
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html 
to setup a express server and then follow stripe.com/docs/charges to add an endpoint. 
Your frontend should issue a POST request to your backend server; I suggest follow closely using https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart

Comment: i want to know that how can i separate it in two file like one for js and all stuff and one for php. so on button click i get data in php then make a charge because it run the php first rather than js